# Drop Database Scoped Credential

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a database in Azure that I need to move to a local database.

I use the SSMS to Export a .bacpak file, and then connect to my local version of Sql Server and attempt to import it.

The import begins, but then fails on this line

```
Create database scoped credential...
```

This feature is available in Azure, but not in Sql Server 2014 (It will be in 2016).

To resolve, I went to the Azure Database and deleted the credential with SSMS.

So the credential is no longer visible in SSMS.

I then created a new export, and tried to import it.  But I am getting the same error message. In other words, the script is still trying to create the credential even though it was removed from the database.

Is there something else I need to do to fully remove the Credential?  I have tried the export/import several times just to make sure I wasn't importing the original file, but I am sure that is not the case. Is there a compact command or something that needs to be run to fully flush the changes to the database?

Comment: Which SSMS version is used? For me, the import (with credential) works fine in 12.0.4100.1. Do you have no more records in `sys.database_credentials` in Azure db?

Comment: Yes, indeed, there is a record in there. I will see if I can delete it somehow.

Comment: Success.  I used the "Drop Database Scoped Credential" and it removed it from the table. @IlyaChumakov if you post as answer, I will accept.

Comment: Glad to see you resolved the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [`sys.database_credentials`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270282.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) view in Azure SQL database and remove rest of credentials (if exists) with [`DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270271.aspx) command.

Comment: drop command is not working "Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Cannot drop the credential 'user', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." though its admin user. Any other way around?

Answer (score 3):

> For short term mitigation we provide you PowerShell script that do the following:
>
> 1. Remove the master key object from the bacpac
> 2. Remove the credential object from the bacpac
> 3. After running this PS script on the bacpac you will have new bacpac file with "patched" suffix.
>
> Download it [here](https://github.com/yochananrachamim/AzureSQL/blob/master/RemoveMasterKeyFrombacpac.zip?raw=true)
>
> example:
>
> `C:\PS> .\RemoveMasterKey.ps1  -bacpacPath "C:\BacPacs\Test.bacpac"`

[Original Post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/03/30/exported-database-from-azure-sql-failed-to-be-imported-to-azure-sql-or-to-local-sql-server/): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/03/30/exported-database-from-azure-sql-failed-to-be-imported-to-azure-sql-or-to-local-sql-server/

Comment: This worked for me as well. It even worked for me on SQL Express.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts! Even as a temporary solution, it still means a lot, because in some cases you can't control the whole architecture that's involved.